# Changing the component type on an ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I've got a component on my form (*id="theDocument"*) that I want to render differently under certain circumstances.

If '*myBean.theDocument*' exists, I want it to render as a *p:commandLink*, but if it doesn't exist, I want it to render as plain text e.g. *h:outputText*.

This condition will change after a file upload (after the upload, *myBean.theDocument* will exist, so I want it to render as the *p:commandLink*).

So on my *p:fileUpload*, I have this kind of thing:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{myBean.handleFileUpload}" update="theDocument">
```

I've been using rendered="...", and update works fine for refreshing the value of an existing component. But how do I change the **type** of the component after an ajax update (or do I need to refresh the whole page and make the decision to render as text or a link in a more general way?

Thanks

Comment: If my question isn't clear, let me know and I will try to clarify it: was struggling to come up with the correct words to explain my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have two conditionally rendered components in a common parent and update the common parent.

```
<h:panelGroup id="theDocument">
    <p:commandLink ... rendered="#{not empty myBean.theDocument}" />
    <h:outputText ... rendered="#{empty myBean.theDocument}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```